# VFD - V/F control

Tags: induction-motor, vfd

I am new to VFD. I came across a code where even in simple V/F control for IM, the algorithm uses Phiboost and calculates Vd and Vq. What is the significance of Vd and Vq in simple V/F control ?
Then this Vd and Vq is converterd to Va, Vb and Vc using inverse transformations.

Can't we directly know the voltage level and generate PWM accordingly? Why is it done so?

Comment: Please define Phiboost, Vd and Vq. What code are you referring to? Do you mean some software code or something else?

Comment: I assume Vd and Vq are with regards to DQ transform.

Comment: Phiboost is used for boosting flux at low frequencies to increase torque

Comment: Yes, w.r.t DQ transofrm. and Yes - code meaning software code